# caveat emptor policy

Tags: meaning-in-context

1. The unscrupulous retailer followed the cynical policy of caveat emptor.
2. None of the large department stores can afford to practice the doctrine of caveat emptor.

According to this two sentence why the retailer can follow the caveat emptor but the department stores can't?

Comment: I assume you know what "caveat emptor" means.

Answer (score 1):

"Not given".

There is nothing in these sentences that explains why the retailer can but the department store can't.  They tell you that the first does apply this policy and the second doesn't.  They don't say *why*.

The only hint of a reason is "can't afford to".  It would cost the department stores money (in the long term) if they applied this policy.